Pass a property from an ObservableObject to another ObObject class?
Given I have the ObservableObject that lives on SwiftUI App as the .environmentObject
final class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
   @AppStorage("defaultTaskDuration") var defaultTaskDuration: Int = 1500
   //... other AppStorages
}

(The user might change the defaultTaskDuration via Preferences...)
How to access this in my viewmodel?
@Observable final class TaskDialogViewModel {
    var taskDuration = 0
    func getDefaultTaskDuration() {
          // access defaultTaskDuration
    }
}

What I'm doing now: I pass the value through the View
struct Dialog: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @Environment(TaskDialogViewModel.self) private var model

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ...
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.taskDuration = userSettings.defaultTaskDuration
        }
    }
}

This works. But I wonder if there's a way without passing it to view?

why not use @AppStorage("defaultTaskDuration") var defaultTaskDuration: Int = 1500
in your views, instead of using some ObservableObject to pass it in.
This is what AppStorage is for.

Because: this way I can encapsulate all @AppStorage in one class and pass it around to different views and settings. So it doesn't clutter my view.

To have your class with all the @AppStorage available
to all views, without passing it to the Views, try using a singleton pattern.
eg, static var shared = UserSettings(), then use UserSettings.shared.defaultTaskDuration

Am I missing something? Just access it with UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "defaultTaskDuration")? Or use object(forKey:) and check for nil to provide your own default value.

Dito. However, if you absolutely want to use SwiftUI's Environment, you may define a parent view which reads the environment variable. It then passes it down to its child view, which creates the view model taking the environment value as parameter in its init. Also, don't put a ViewModel (MVVM) into the environment. The ViewModel and View should have a 1:1 relationship - also regarding their life-times. Your VM is probably not a View Model.
